# Select data in range from first bad value to last bad value

Tags: clickhouse

Have such table and data:

```
create table sensor_values(
    dt DateTime default now(),
    value UInt32
)
engine MergeTree()
partition by toYYYYMM(dt)
order by tuple();

insert into sensor_values(value) values (1), (2), (11), (13), (4), (17), (5), (8);
```

Data:

```
value
-----
1
2
11
13
4
17
5
8
```

I would like to select data in range from first bad value (11) to last bad value (17). Bad values are more than 10.

Desired range after select:

```
value
-----
11
13
4
17
```

My first thoughts were to define whether value bad or not and then to calculate (some how) accumulative sum:

```
value  isBad  cumSum
--------------------
1      0      0
2      0      0
11     1      1
13     1      2
4      0      2
17     1      3
5      0      3
8      0      3
```

Then I would select from min(cumSum) to max(cumSum) - 1 but I miss last bad value.

How can I get the last value included in select result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use either the window-functions (see: [runningDifference](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5D+runningDifference), [neighbor](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5D+neighbor)) or array-functions:

```sql
SELECT arrayJoin(slice) as result
FROM (
    SELECT
        groupArray(data) AS arr,
        arrayFirstIndex(x -> (x > 10), arr) AS first_index,
        (length(arr) - arrayFirstIndex(x -> (x > 10), arrayReverse(arr)) + 1) AS last_index,
        arraySlice(arr, first_index, last_index - first_index + 1) AS slice    
    FROM 
    (
        /* test dataset */
        SELECT arrayJoin([1, 2, 11, 13, 4, 17, 5, 8]) AS data
    )
)
/*
┌─result─┐
│     11 │
│     13 │
│      4 │
│     17 │
└────────┘
*/
```